# Why would anyone prefer static strategy over the dynamic one?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

```
#include <iostream>

class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class Strategy1 : public Strategy
{
public:

    virtual void execute() override { std::cout << "executed1\n"; }
};

class Strategy2 : public Strategy
{
public:

    virtual void execute() override { std::cout << "executed2\n"; }
};

template <typename S>
class StaticStrategy
{
    S strategy;

public:

    void execute()
    {
        strategy.execute();
    }
};

class DynamicStrategy
{
    Strategy* strategy;

public:

    DynamicStrategy(Strategy* strategy) : strategy(strategy) {}

    void execute()
    {
        strategy->execute();
    }

    void setStrategy(Strategy* newStrategy)
    {
        delete strategy;
        strategy = newStrategy;
    }

    ~DynamicStrategy()
    {
        delete strategy;
    }
};

int main()
{
    StaticStrategy<Strategy1> staticStrategy;
    staticStrategy.execute();

    DynamicStrategy dynamicStrategy(new Strategy1{});
    dynamicStrategy.execute();

    dynamicStrategy.setStrategy(new Strategy2{});
    dynamicStrategy.execute();
}
```

Here is an example of the static and the dynamic strategy pattern written in c++. I wonder why would someone use a static strategy instead of a dynamic one. It seems like the dynamic one does all the job of the static one but also have more flexibility since the strategy can be changed at run time. Can anyone give me an example where a static strategy would be better that a dynamic one?

Comment: The static strategy is easier to work with, and less error prone, less likely to leak memory, less likely to violate the [Rule Of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), etc etc etc. However, at the same time, your example is putting the static data in automatic memory on the call stack, which is a very limited resource compared to dynamic memory.

Comment: The static one works with every type that has an `execute` function, the dynamic one requires the strategy be derived from `Strategy`.

Comment: From performance point of view static has less runtime overhead (but can bloat code). Dynamic should dynamic dispatch (virtual method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static version is strictly more powerful and easier to use in some ways.

The static version only requires that `S` have a member function `execute`, whereas the dynamic version imposes upon the user inheritance from `Strategy`.

The static version places no requirements on allocation strategy or lifetime, whereas in the snippet the dynamic version requires heap allocation. An alternative of the dynamic version is possible without allocation if it does not take ownership, in which case the client must be concerned with the `Strategy` lifetime.

Given the static version, a client who wants heap allocation can erase the strategy type to have heap allocation with a single strategy type. But given the dynamic version above, a client cannot undo the requirement for heap allocation.

The static version is completely visible to the compiler and this information is available for optimization. The dynamic version indirects through the `Strategy` base class, so inlining cannot occur unless the compiler can prove (or speculate) the concrete `Strategy` class being used.

Comment: Both versions can use stack or heap allocation (even if heap allocation is strange for static version).

Comment: How you you proposing to use stack allocation with the dynamic version?

Comment: I suppose ref/ptr and have DynamicStrategy not accept ownership. That leaves the lifetime issue. I probably could find a way to word that better.

Comment: `Strategy1 s1{}; DynamicStrategy dynamicStrategy(&s1);`

Comment: With the code in the Q, that's UB. You'd have to make DynamicStrategy not accept ownership. And then client has to worry about lifetime.

Comment: Need to adapte OP code indeed. Using appropriate smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` can even handle both case.